# UWP C# Wait Until File Does Not Exist

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I'm creating a Windows UWP store app in C# and need a little help please.

Scenario:

A user selects an audio file which they want to rename based on an audio fingerprint. Once the audio file is selected the app writes the name of the selected file to a text file. The app then calls FullTrustProcessLauncher to launch a trusted app. The app it calls is a console application I have written which loads a fingerprint generator to grab the fingerprint for the current file (the fingerprint generator has to be launched from command prompt) and it then takes the generated print and stores that in a file for use later on in my main app. During the generator process my console application creates a "lock" file and deletes it upon exit.

My problem is that my UWP application continues to run the rest of the code before the console application finishes, which throws out errors because the fingerprint has not been generated. My question is, does anyone know a way where I can prevent the app from continuing until the "lock" file has been deleted. I cannot check for a process because UWP doesn't have the Process api available due to security restrictions.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you have read the "lock" file? But you can not know, if it is been deleted?

Comment: Yes exactly, read the file and then do not proceed until the file has been removed